# Unity3D Prevent adding certain built-in components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components

I have made my own component which conflicts with some Unity built-in components (like Rigidbody conflicts with Rigidbody2D). So I need to be sure that those components will not exist together in the same GameObject. Is there a way to do it? It seems to be easy to check when my own component is added (by [Reset](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html)), but what to do if Unity' built-in component is added? Is there some callback, message, or event sent when new component attached to the GameObject?

**Precisions**

I do not need to hide components it in the editor, or prevent adding my own components. I am asking about preventing adding certain Unity' **built-in** components while my component is attached. From both Editor GUI (by "[add component](https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/50917-unity-problem.png)" button) and Unity API (by [GameObject.AddComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)).

Comment: Do you need to make this check at runtime?

Comment: @Ambo100 at runtime and in the editor also

Comment: The duplicate explains how to do this.

Comment: @Programmer I do not need to hide components it in the editor. I need a solution which prevents adding certain Unity' built-in components while my component is attached. From both Editor GUI (by "add component" button) and Unity API (by GameObject.AddComponent).

Comment: Hiding component is a **part** of the other question but not the main question there. The main question(See title) is about preventing adding component to a GameObject. Please read the second part of my answer there.

Comment: @Programmer That solution does not allows to prevent adding Unity built-in components (RigidBody, RigidBody2D, etc.), and that's what I am asking about.

Comment: Ok. The built-in keyword edit in the title made me re-open it as the duplicate does not address that. What you want to do is complicated. Did you find a solution or still looking for one?

Comment: @Programmer Still looking.

Comment: Check my answer. It's long. Just don't copy the code. Read how it works and why I used some API so that you will understand how to improve it or re-write it if necessary. Also, only comment when you have tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some callback, message, or event sent when new component
>   attached to the GameObject?

No.

> Is there a way to do it?

Yes, but a bit complicated.

If you want to prevent your custom script from being added, that would have been easy and [this](http://Prevent%20component%20from%20being%20added%20in%20the%20Editor) question should handle that.

This is complicated because you want to prevent a component written by another person(built-in) from being added to a `GameObject` which means that you first need a way to detect when that component has been added to a `GameObject` then destroy it. **This has to be done every frame** (Both in the Editor and during run-time).

You can call the components you don't want to be added to a `GameObject` *blacklisted components*.

Here are the steps:

**1**.Store the blacklisted components in an array.

```
private static Type[] blacklistedComponents =
{
    typeof(Rigidbody),
    typeof(Rigidbody2D)
    //...
};
```

**2**.Get the root `GameObjects` in the scene and store them in a List.

```
private static List<GameObject> rootGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
Scene.GetRootGameObjects(rootGameObjects);
```

**3**.Loop through each root `GameObject` and use `GetComponentsInChildren` to get all the components attached to each `GameObject` under that root `GameObject`.

```
private static List<Component> allComponents = new List<Component>();
currentLoopRoot.GetComponentsInChildren<Component>(true, allComponents);
```

**4**.During the loop from **#3**, loop through the retrieved components and check if it has any blacklisted component. If it does, destroy that blacklisted component.

```
for (int i = 0; i < allComponents.Count; i++)
{
    //Loop through each blacklisted Component and see if it is present
    for (int j = 0; j < blacklistedComponents.Length; j++)
    {
        if (allComponents[i].GetType() == blacklistedComponents[j])
        {
            Debug.Log("Found Blacklisted Component: " + targetComponents[i].GetType().Name);
            Debug.Log("Removing Blacklisted Component");
            //Destroy Component
            DestroyImmediate(allComponents[i]);

            Debug.LogWarning("This component is now destroyed");
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. You or others may have few questions about this answer.

**Q 1**.*Wonder why `FindObjectsOfType` and `FindObjectsOfTypeAll` are not used?*

**A 1**.These functions are usually used to simplify getting everything in the scene but the problem is that they return array. Calling these functions every frame will kill your game performance since it allocates memory and will cause garbage collector to run more often.

This is why `Scene.GetRootGameObjects` is used which you can pass a `List` inside it and it will fill the list for you. It does not return array.

---

**Q 2**.*Why did you pass List to `GetComponentsInChildren` and not return the result from it?*

**A 2**. Technically the-same reason I explained above. I used a version of the `GetComponentsInChildren` function that does not allocate memory. Simply pass `List` to it and it will fill it up with every component it found. This prevents it from returning an array which is expensive.

---

I wrote a complete working code for this below but you need to improve it. That's why I explained every process so that you can either improve or rewrite it yourself. It currently prevents `Rigidbody` and `Rigidbody2D` from being added from the Editor or from code in the Editor or in a build.You can add more components you want to block to the `blacklistedComponents` variable. It runs in the Editor also during runtime. `UNITY_EDITOR` is used to remove the Editor codes and make sure that it compiles for platforms.

**1**.Create a script called `ComponentDetector` and copy every code below into it.

**2**.Save and go back to the Editor. That's it. You don't have to attach it to any Object. **You should never be able to add `Rigidbody` and `Rigidbody2D` to any GameObject.**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class ComponentDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Add the blacklisted Components here
    private static Type[] blacklistedComponents =
        {
        typeof(Rigidbody),
        typeof(Rigidbody2D)
        //...
    };

    private static List<Component> allComponents = new List<Component>();
    private static List<GameObject> rootGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    private static void GetAllRootObject()
    {
        Scene activeScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        activeScene.GetRootGameObjects(rootGameObjects);
    }

    private static void GetAllComponentsAndCheckIfBlacklisted()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rootGameObjects.Count; ++i)
        {
            GameObject obj = rootGameObjects[i];
            //Debug.Log(obj.name);

            //Get all child components attached to this GameObject
            obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Component>(true, allComponents);

            //Remove component if present in the blacklist array
            RemoveComponentIfBlacklisted(allComponents, blacklistedComponents);
        }


    }

    private static void RemoveComponentIfBlacklisted(List<Component> targetComponents, Type[] blacklistedList)
    {
        //Loop through each target Component
        for (int i = 0; i < targetComponents.Count; i++)
        {
            //Debug.Log(targetComponents[i].GetType());
            //Loop through each blacklisted Component and see if it is present
            for (int j = 0; j < blacklistedList.Length; j++)
            {
                if (targetComponents[i].GetType() == blacklistedList[j])
                {
                    Debug.Log("Found Blacklisted Component: " + targetComponents[i].GetType().Name);
                    Debug.LogError("You are not allowed to add the " + targetComponents[i].GetType().Name + " component to a GameObject");
                    Debug.Log("Removing Blacklisted Component");
                    //Destroy Component
                    DestroyImmediate(targetComponents[i]);

                    Debug.LogWarning("This component is now destroyed");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SearchAndRemoveblacklistedComponents()
    {
        //Get all root GameObjects
        GetAllRootObject();

        //Get all child components attached to each GameObject and remove them
        GetAllComponentsAndCheckIfBlacklisted();
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log("Update: Run-time");
        SearchAndRemoveblacklistedComponents();
    }
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[InitializeOnLoad]
class ComponentDetectorEditor
{
    static ComponentDetectorEditor()
    {
        createComponentDetector();
        EditorApplication.update += Update;
    }

    static void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log("Update: Editor");
        ComponentDetector.SearchAndRemoveblacklistedComponents();
    }

    static void createComponentDetector()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("___CDetector___");
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = new GameObject("___CDetector___");
        }

        //Hide from the Editor
        obj.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
        obj.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector;

        ComponentDetector cd = obj.GetComponent<ComponentDetector>();
        if (cd == null)
        {
            cd = obj.AddComponent<ComponentDetector>();
        }

    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: *"I am asking about preventing adding certain Unity' built-in components while my component is attached"* I focused on what's on the title of this question so that this question can be re-usable to other users but you can easily do that with this answer. I left that part for you to do which is easy if you read this answer. When the blacklisted component is found in the `if (targetComponents[i].GetType() == blacklistedList[j])` line of code, you can use `GetComponent` to check if the current `targetComponents` has your `Rigidbody` and your `CustomRigidbody` then destroy it.

Comment: Simply add `if (targetComponents[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>()
    && targetComponents[i].GetComponent<CustomRigidbody>())
{
    //Destroy Component
    DestroyImmediate(targetComponents[i]);
}` **inside** `if (targetComponents[i].GetType() == blacklistedList[j])`. Also, move all the old code and Debug statements inside that new `if` statement. That's it. You can add as many `else if` statements to cover all your `if` components.

Comment: Your second comment is invalid and is just a **rant**. 1.The code in that answer does not return all the GameObjects or all the components at a time. It returns the root GameObjects which is simply storing GameObject which is an Object not an image or a huge data. 2.It loops through each **root** GameObject and get all children components in each loop. It does not get all the components in the scene at a time. Resources should not be an issue. 3.It does not even return an array. It uses list to fill the object. All these are mentioned in my answer but you didn't read them.

Comment: 4.It works on both Editor and runtime. You simply decided to make that  random comment. Finally, it does not store **bazillion** of objects/components. It gets few from each root object, perform action on it, resets and moves on to the next object. If I wanted to get all the Objects at once, I would have used `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll` or `FindObjectsOfType` which I clearly mentioned in my answer that I did not want to do that in my answer. Read the answer again for I actually did and not just the code! Use my second comment to get what you wanted in your first comment.

Comment: I am not using recursion in that code. Looping through a List/array does not equals to performing recursion. Your should probably Google "recursion".  Getting all the components/objects at the-same time requires using functions which allocate memory. Allocating that amount of memory required to hold the result will slow down the loop and increase the "processor ticks". Also, it will cause GC to run leading to your game freezing temporary once in a while.I mentioned about GC in my answer. Again, you didn't read that.

Comment: Your rants: 1. *"which makes solution on it to be run only in editor/debug modes"* 2. *"may not run even there if scene has bazillion of components"*. 3. *"which excludes potentially important error messages in release builds" * 4.*"it requires dozen resources to maintain"* You just kept saying long stuff that sounds off from what's in this solution. At this point, your issue should be solved. My answer will stay here for people that will run into this issue in the future and I will use it to mark them as duplicate. Have a nice day and happy coding!

Comment: Okay, tested it carefully, it works much better then I thought, there might be no big performance issues, sorry for that, it makes it a good solution for debug and editor purposes.

Comment: But about second part of the question, what will you recommend for choosing what to destroy? For example: MyRigidbody conflicts with RigidBody. After check I know that object has both of them. So what should I destroy? Logic says that I should destroy the newest, but is there something like a time of component creation? (or I should create my dictionary with creation times?) Or destroy by order? (is GetComponentsInChildren() order guaranteed?) But what if component changes it's order itself?

Comment: You are complicating stuff unnecessary for you. You are the one to decide which one to destroy. You have two choices: 1.Destroy the built-in component. 2.Destroy the custom component. This is really up to you to decide which one to destroy not me. All you have to do is this `DestroyImmediate(targetComponents[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>());` to destroy the built in component or `DestroyImmediate(targetComponents[i].GetComponent<MyRigidbody>());` to destroy your custom component. That's totally up to you to decide and no Dictionary should be involved in this.

Comment: Okay. Seems like the only disadvantage here is that there is no way to view stack trace of creating conflicted component. E.g. if I will call some CheckConflict() inside Awake(), I can easily (if object is active) move to the line of code where component is created and fix it, just like it is done with built-in components (built-in check also is working on disabled objects).

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`[DisallowMultipleComponent]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DisallowMultipleComponent.html) attribute which prevents two of the same type from being added to the same game object. This works for subtypes as well (which is how Rigidbody and Rigidbody2d are handled).

I am not sure if this will work for you or not, as you haven't said your components are related to each other, but it is what I can find.

Comment: Yes, this is nice attribute, but it will not help, my components are not derived from built-in (and can not, most of them are sealed). And this attribute is not used for resolving conflicts between RigidBody and RigidBody2D, as it works only on class and its derivatives (both of them are derived from Component, and objects can have multiple components e.g. Transform is derived from Component). And if you will notice, the message is different, when you try to add RigidBody when RigidBody2D is already added. Unity clearly states it as a conflict and that's what do I need to reproduce.

Comment: @VictorF Alas, this is the only information I could find that's even close.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to determine if the component exists before runtime, which I assume you already know, you can use the `Start()` method. But, like I said, I assume you already know that, so the only other way to check something like that during runtime would be to continually check for it in the `Update()` method, every frame. Although, I am not sure as to why a Unity component might be added to a gameobject during runtime. If this is an issue, maybe the component in question could be added to a child or parent gameobject instead?

If you really feel like making some changes, which may require a lot of refactoring for your project, you could always create a `ComponentManager` class that handles adding and removing components to GameObjects and create your own callbacks.